# top() is not functioning with JavaPairRDD in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have extended the existing WordCount example in java explained on official site of Apache Spark. The extensions are :

1. Sorting of tuples according to their more existance.
   e.g: Existing unsorted order :
        (nec,8), (eu,11), (sit,7)
        My desired sorted order:
        (eu,11), (nec,8), (sit,7)
2. Take top 3 from the sorted list.
   Sorting is done fine, but top() is not working on JavaPairRDD. Let me paste my code..
   Other methods are same, so I am writing my main method here:

> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) {
>       if (args.length < 1) {
>           System.err
>                   .println("Please provide the input file full path as argument");
>           System.exit(0);
>       }
> ```

```
        SparkConf conf = new        SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> file = context.textFile(args[0]);
        JavaRDD<String> words = file.flatMap(WORDS_EXTRACTOR);

        /*Pairs with key= words and values=no.of occurances*/
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(WORDS_MAPPER);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counter = pairs.reduceByKey(WORDS_REDUCER);

        // First swapping (making key= no.of occurance and value=words... to allow sort based on no.of  occurances)
       JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> swappedPair = counter.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,     Integer>, Integer, String>() {
            public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> item) throws Exception {
                return item.swap();
            }

        });

        // after swapping tuples are sorted based on no.of occurances   
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> sortedCounter = swappedPair.sortByKey(false);

        // Reverse the swapping
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> reverseSwappedPair = sortedCounter.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<Integer, String>, String, Integer>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<Integer, String> item) throws Exception {
                return item.swap();
            }

        });
       **reverseSwappedPair.top(3)**;
        reverseSwappedPair.saveAsTextFile(args[1]);

      }
}
```

Without bold(**) line, remaining code is running fine and gives correct result means sorted order of tuples based on word's no. of existance. I write the red line to get top 3 sorted tuples, but it gives the exception shown below. I tried other JavaDD option as well,

JavaRDD co =  JavaRDD.fromRDD(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(reverseSwappedPair), ReverseSwappedPair.classTag());
co.top(3);

But it is also giving the same exception as below. Kindly help me to solve this issue. I tried other options as well but no result.

```
Exception:
15/06/23 07:21:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at com.google.common.collect.NaturalOrdering.compare(NaturalOrdering.java:26)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7.compare(Ordering.scala:153)
    at scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4.compare(Ordering.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$$anon$1.compare(Utils.scala:35)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.max(Ordering.java:572)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:688)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/06/23 07:21:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at com.google.common.collect.NaturalOrdering.compare(NaturalOrdering.java:26)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$7.compare(Ordering.scala:153)
    at scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4.compare(Ordering.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$$anon$1.compare(Utils.scala:35)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.max(Ordering.java:572)
    at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:688)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another API : java.util.List top(int num,
                    java.util.Comparator comp)

It can not directly compare two tuples. Write your custom comparator. Hope this will help

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me sample code example. I really need this

Comment: You need to implement a compartor as (This is just example. Please change comparator's logic as per your need) <br>

`private static class CustomComaprator implements Serializable, Comparator {
  public int compare(Object o11, Object o12) {
   Tuple2<String, Integer> o1 = (Tuple2<String, Integer>) o11;
   Tuple2<String, Integer> o2 = (Tuple2<String, Integer>) o12;
   if (o1._2 > o2._2) {
    return o1._2;
   }else{
    return o2._2;
   }

  }
 }`

And while using top API, use it as follows: 

`reverseSwappedPair.top(3, new CustomComaprator())`

Very sorry for the formatting issues.